# PPT VBA close an item in the Presentations collection

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm using Slides.InsertFromFile to insert slides from a separate PPTM into an open PPTM. This causes the source PPTM to be added to the Presentations collection. I'd like to remove it from the collection after the slide insertion. The following isn't removing the source PPTM from the collection, any suggestions?

```
With Presentations.Item(IndexOfSourcePPTM)
                        .Saved = msoTrue 
                        .Close
                    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Whew, got it working.
Here's how I opened the PPTM that I want to close later:

```
Set TheNewlyOpenedTandemPresentation = Presentations.Open(TandemFileToLoadFilePath, msoFalse, msoFalse, msoTrue)  'filepath,readonly,untitled/ascopy, visiblewindow
```

Later, I loop backwards and just .Close

```
Dim ThePresentationCounter As Integer
    For ThePresentationCounter = Presentations.Count To 1 Step -1
        If StrComp(Presentations(ThePresentationCounter).Name, CurrentTandemFileName) = 0 Then
            Presentations(ThePresentationCounter).Close
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Hopefully not counting my chick'ns ... now I need to make this work with presentations with no visible window when opened